# How to validate new SAML certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, saml, onelogin

I'm working on an app that acts as a SAML service provider.  It's written in Rails and uses the omniauth-saml and ruby-saml gems.

Our certificate is about to expire, and we need to create a new one.  I'm tasked with verifying that the new one is working.  However, none of the IdPs that I've tested with seem to care which certificate I use.  When I set them up with the old cert and then switch our app to using the new one they all allow SP-initiated login as if nothing changed.

The app needs to work with all IdPs, and I think that some of them do validate assertion signatures.  I need to find an IdP that fails to accept an SP-initiated login assertion when the signature does not match the one that was set up.  I've tried Okta, Jumpcloud, and Ping without any luck.

One question is: why don't these IdPs care about the signature for SP-initiated login.  But the main question is: how do I find one that does care so that I can test the new cert?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two places where your SP's certificate is used: (1) the SP can digitally sign its authentication request to the IdP, and (2) the IdP can encrypt parts of its response with your SP's public key.

For situation (1), if your SP is signing its requests with the new certificate but the IdP responds as before, it could very well be that the IdP is simply ignoring the signature. The IdP might have to be configured to expect and require signed requests before it will fail on an unknown certificate. But note that it is up to the IdP whether it will verify signed requests; for example, according to [this post](https://support.okta.com/help/answers?id=906F0000000I06zIAC&feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=xMFA&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&) Okta does not verify the signature of signed authentication requests.

For situation (2) use Firefox's SAML tracer or something similar to verify that part of the response from the IdP is encrypted. If not, that would explain why switching to a new certificate that the IdP does not know about continues to work.

It may also be that your SP needs only to know that the person authenticated successfully against the IdP and nothing else, in which case, your SP's certificate is superfluous.

In particular, the [Shibboleth IdP](https://shibboleth.net/products/identity-provider.html) can be configured to send back encrypted assertions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The tips about encrypted assertions and the SAML tracer were very good to know.  It looks like most IdPs do not require signed login requests.  The one that we integrate with that does is ADFS.  We validated our certificate by setting up a test ADFS server and showing that when it changed the login requests were rejected.

Answer (score 0):

For me, by far the easiest to use and configure IdP or SP test connectors can be found here: https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector

There is a list of test connectors that will help you to test different kinds of connections.